# Graphics performing bad on Fedora22, error in libGL?

Tags: linux, matlab, graphics, fedora

I have problem with graphic on my Fedora system. I see shaking of the window, and that is mostly happening when I scroll through the page, but also I see the error when I want to run MATLAB from command line, I get an error:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing  
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600  
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so  
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast  
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks very much like an issue I had/have with one of my debian systems, and it's a problem with the graphics drivers. I'd start by reinstalling them, and then see where you are...

Comment: I tried that. Only if I didn't make any mistake. I see that I have lot of installed drivers xorg-x11-drv... But I can't find which one is loaded. I hope the one for ATI Radeon Card.

Comment: I'm sure I used to know a more elegant way of checking which video drivers were loaded, but I can't remember it. The following works though: run `lsmod | grep vgastate`, and then run `sudo modinfo {}`, replacing the curly braces with the alphanumeric string on the right of the things `lsmod` displayed (on this computer, I get `vga16fb`). This should show you what video driver is running from where...

Comment: The command lsmod | grep vgastate  doesn't give anything.  But for lsmod | grep radeon, and modinfo, I get:/lib/modules/4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64+debug/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko.xz

Comment: I'm afraid this is where I get off - I don't understand how fedora does graphic drivers - I'm a debian person... I'd imagine that you'd have more success posting on superuser (another stackexchange site - you can use the same login) as it's a more general linux problem you have than it is a programming problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was using Fedora 16, 18 but now I have problems with 22. Everything was smooth before.